# Selecting specific featureclasses in result list of arcpy.da.Walk()?

Tags: arcpy

I am a complete (!) novice in Python.

I have a list of access DB (MDB) that each have 1 or 2 featureclasses that i have to select

example :

```
B:\map1\DB1.mdb\Feature1
B:\map1\DB1.mdb\Feature1_Corrected
B:\map2\DB2.mdb\Feature1
B:\map2\DB2.mdb\Feature1_Corrected 
B:\map3\DB2.mdb\Feature1
B:\map4\DB2.mdb\Feature1
B:\map5\DB5.mdb\Feature1
B:\map5\DB5.mdb\Feature1_Corrected
```

and so on

unpredictible which Db has 1 or 2 featureclasses

Now I want to append feature1 - if only feature1 exists - or feature1_corrected if both exist to a featureclass in another GDB

I have found the 'walk' function and can append a list to the new GDB but i am a lost in how to write the correct if/then/else statements to select the correct featureclasses during the walk.

I added the script so far below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# script to append features that are located in different DB in different maps
# Bart De Wachter - länsstyrelsen Jämtland
# januari 2016
#
# step 1: create list of relevant sjo features - use "walk" -
# step 2: loop for every filename in list
## step 2a: append to feature  (FISK.gdb)
## step 2b: add vattensystem in correct attribute - get info from mapname
# step 3: same procedure for VDR

import datetime

## Timestamp shows
print 'Startar skript vid: \t\t' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
starttid = datetime.datetime.now()

#start with import of relevenat modules
import arcpy, codecs, os
print u'Import av bibliotek färdig: \t' + str(datetime.datetime.now())


# define workspace  
workspace = r"B:\GIS\fisk_kunskap\test"
print 'directory = ' + workspace


### STEP 1 ###
# creat list of featureclasses  
feature_classes = []

# walk through all directories and databases and find polygon Featureclasses
# works for .MDB and .GDB
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:

        for filename in filenames:
            feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

print feature_classes 

### STEP 2 ###
# keep only relevant featureclasses
# 






### STEP 3 ###
# appends all från feature_classes (list) to specific Featureclass in .GDB
# outfile is where objects are appended
# Schema type = tests if fields are the same; NoTest doesn't check

outfile = r"B:\GIS\fisk_kunskap\Out\OUT.gdb\sjo_all"
schemaType = "NO_TEST"
fieldMappings = ""
subtype = ""

# Process: Append the feature classes into the empty feature class

arcpy.Append_management(feature_classes, outfile, schemaType, fieldMappings, subtype)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter the feature classes during the walk statement.

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(
    workspace, datatype = 'FeatureClass', type = 'Polygon'):
    for dirname in dirnames:
        arcpy.env.workspace = os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
        #List feature classes in the geodatabase
        fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
        #If there is only one, append it
        if len(fcs) == 1:
            feature_classes.append(fcs[0])
        #If more than one, find the corrected one and append it
        elif len(fcs) > 1:
            correct_fcs = [fc for fc in fcs if 'Corrected' in fc]
            feature_classes.append(correct_fcs[0])
print feature_classes
```